# dbWriteTable operation in RSQLite become slower

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dataframe

I want to insert data frames into `sqlite` table. The data frame contains thousands of rows. I am now using `RSQLite` package for database operation. For inserting data frame into table i am using `dbWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...)` method. But the repeated insertion to the table makes the program slower. Is there any other better option to insert data frame into a table? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use explicit transactions, each SQL statement is wrapped into an automatic transaction.
At the end of each transaction, the data is synchronized with the disk.

Wrap all inserts into a single transaction.

Comment: what about using commit or rollback after insertion?

Comment: Yes, that's what you do at the end of a transaction.